# How do you find the derivative of the $\int_{1-x}^{1+2x} e^{t^2} dt$?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{1-x}^{1+2x} e^{t^2} dt$$
I don't fully understand the steps taken to answer this question. If someone could please tell me the steps for this kind of a situation I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{1-x}^{1+2x}e^{t^2}dt \; = \; \int_{1-x}^{0}e^{t^2}dt \; + \; \int_{0}^{1+2x}e^{t^2}dt    \; = \; -\int^{1-x}_{0}e^{t^2}dt \; + \; \int_{0}^{1+2x}e^{t^2}dt $$

Answer (score 0):

Assume the primitive (or antiderivative) of $e^{t^2}$ is $G(t)$, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have:

$\int_{1-x}^{1+2x}e^{t^2}dt=G(1+2x)-G(1-x)$

Now (by the chain rule) :

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(G(1+2x)-G(1-x))=(1+2x)'G'(1+2x)-(1-x)'G'(1-x)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\,=2e^{(1+2x)^2}+e^{(1-x)^2}$